# Linq how to move all values of two columns to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to move 2 columns of my table to an another table. I can select values that i want to move but i'am unable to move them. How can i make this ? Here is my implementation

```
var cartQuery = (from c in db.CartTbls.AsQueryable()
                                 join cs in db.CartShoeTbls on c.CartID equals cs.CartID
                                 where c.CustomerID == cusID
                                 select new {c.CustomerID,c.TotalPrice,cs.ShoeID,cs.Quantity});
```

What i want to do is copy the all values of ShoeID and Quantity attiributes. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What properties do you have in target entity? Do you have separate table corresponding to that target entity?

Comment: Please, explain a little bit more what you're trying to do. Which is the origin table, which is the destination, how many records do you have to move, on what contidion...

Comment: You say you want to "move" the data, does that mean you want it removed from the source table, or do you just need it _copied_ to the other table?

Comment: This query returns values from origin table and i got a destination table also and their attiributes are matching. I want to delete datas from origin table after i move them.

Comment: Can you show us the name of the destination table?

Comment: @Stefan it is OrderShoeTbl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert/Select with Linq-To-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080915/insert-select-with-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use should add the selection to the table and save the changes:

```
foreach (var item in cartQuery)
    db.OrderShoeTbl.Add(new OrderShoe()
        { ShoeID = item.ShoeID, Quantity = item.Quantity });

db.SaveChanges();
```

if you are using Linq to SQL, the insert is different and should look like this:

```
foreach (var item in cartQuery)
    db.OrderShoeTbl.InsertOnSubmit(new OrderShoe()
        { ShoeID = item.ShoeID, Quantity = item.Quantity });

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: There is no add method for DestinationTable

Comment: @Tartat, you need to put the name of your destination table there. It should be generated in the same way `CartTbls` is.

Comment: I put my destination table's name instead of it but still there is no add method

Comment: @Tartat: what linq provider are you using? Linq 2 SQL? Linq 2 Entities? Entity framework? Please check update.

Comment: i am using linq 2 sql

Answer (score 3):

Stefan's answer is OK however you may insert everything in one step:

```
var cartQuery = (from c in db.CartTbls.AsQueryable()
        join cs in db.CartShoeTbls on c.CartID equals cs.CartID
        where c.CustomerID == cusID
        select new OrderShoeTbl{ShoeID = c.ShoeID, Quantity = c.Quantity});

    db.OrderShoeTbl.InsertAllOnSubmit(cartQuery);

    db.SubmitChanges();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to delete data from source table I would also wrap everything in single transaction to avoid inconsistency in case of errors.

Comment: VS2012 says ShoeID and Quantity does not exists in current context

Comment: Provided `DestTableEntity` is the object Tartar wants to select. :)

Comment: @Tartar make sure that they exist in source and target entities

Comment: I'am sure that they are exist

Comment: @Stefan: destination table is not the source one according comment: "This query returns values from origin table and i got a destination table also and their attiributes are matching"

Comment: This solution is not usefull when try to implement it is full of compile errors

Comment: @Tartar: you have to replace `DestTableEntity` and `DestTable` with your particular names. You did not provide them in question...

Comment: System.NotSupportedException in line `db.DestTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(cartQuery);`

Comment: @Tartar: adjusted to your dest. table name