# Can I Insert the Results of a Select Statement Into Another Table Without a Roundtrip?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a web application that is written in MVC.Net using C# and LINQ-to-SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2).

I'd like to query the database for some values, and also insert those values into another table for later use. Obviously, I could do a normal select, then take those results and do a normal insert, but that will result in my application sending the values back to the SQL server, which is a waste as the server is where the values came from.

Is there any way I can get the select results in my application and insert them into another table without the information making a roundtrip from the the SQL server to my application and back again?

It would be cool if this was in one query, but that's less important than avoiding the roundtrip.

Assume whatever basic schema you like, I'll be extrapolating your simple example to a much more complex query.

Comment: I believe stored procedure is used for that purpose. Have you explored that option?

Comment: @SBirthare That's occurred to me, but we would really prefer to be able to issue the command from C# without having to write a separate stored procedure. It's easier for us to maintain and work with.

Comment: Interesting... I will be keen to know how you achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I Insert the Results of a Select Statement Into Another Table Without a Roundtrip?

From a "single-query" and/or "avoid the round-trip" perspective: Yes.

From a "doing that purely in Linq to SQL" perspective: Well...mostly ;-).

The three pieces required are:

- The `INSERT...SELECT` construct:
  By using this we get half of the goal in that we have selected data and inserted it. And this is the only way to keep the data entirely at the database server and avoid the round-trip. Unfortunately, this construct is not supported by Linq-to-SQL (or Entity Framework): [Insert/Select with Linq-To-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080915/insert-select-with-linq-to-sql/2081021#2081021)
- The T-SQL [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:
  This allows for doing what is essentially the `tee` command in Unix shell scripting: save *and* display the incoming rows *at the same time*. The `OUTPUT` clause just takes the set of inserted rows and sends it back to the caller, providing the other half of the goal. Unfortunately, this is also not supported by Linq-to-SQL (or Entity Framework). Now, this type of operation can also be achieved across multiple queries when not using `OUTPUT`, but there is really nothing gained since you then either need to a) create a temp table to dump the initial results into that will be used to insert into the table and then selected back to the caller, or b) have some way of knowing which rows that were just inserted into the table are new so that they can be properly selected back to the caller.
- The [DataContext.ExecuteQuery<TResult> (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) method:
  This is needed due to the two required T-SQL pieces not being supported directly in Linq-to-SQL. And even if the clunky approach to avoiding the `OUTPUT` clause is done (assuming it could be done in pure Linq/Lambda expressions), there is still no way around the `INSERT...SELECT` construct that would not be a round-trip.

Hence, multiple queries that are all pure Linq/Lambda expressions equates to a round-trip.

The only way to truly avoid the round-trip should be something like:

```
var _MyStuff = db.ExecuteQuery<Stuffs>(@"
    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col2)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
       SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
       FROM   dbo.Table2 t2
       WHERE  t2.Col4 = {0};",
       _SomeID);
```

And just in case it helps anyone (since I already spent the time looking it up :), the equivalent command for Entity Framework is: [Database.SqlQuery<TElement> (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm. That might work. I don't think I'll need to work with the query afterward, so it shouldn't need to be composable. We have some other ExecuteQuery statements, and it's a little better to work with than a stored procedure. At least it's in the repository.

Comment: @DCShannon : I actually don't use Linq to SQL myself ;-), but this was the only means I saw of issuing custom SQL _and_ getting a result set back. The `OUTPUT` clause is not supported directly so you kinda need to do a custom query if you don't want to call a proc. And since the desire is to keep everything in the app layer, that kinda narrows down the choices :).

Comment: @DCShannon there is another overload of `ExecuteQuery` that you might want to check out.

Comment: @DCShannon : I see the rewording, but it's really all the same thing. I have updated my answer accordingly to clarify. Certainly no harm in waiting a few days to see if someone else might know of a trick, but it doesn't even seem theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this query according your requirement

```
insert into IndentProcessDetails (DemandId,DemandMasterId,DemandQty) ( select DemandId,DemandMasterId,DemandQty from DemandDetails)
```

Comment: This looks like you're trying to do an insert with LINQ's query syntax? I don't think that's even possible.