# Pulling data from one SQL Azure table, add a column, then populate a different table

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-sql-database

I using C# and LINQ to pull/push data housed in SQL Azure. The basic scenario is we have a Customer table that contains all customers (PK = CompanyID) and supporting tables like LaborTypes and Materials (FK CompanyID to Customer table).

When a new customer signs up, a new record is created in the Customers table. Once that is complete, I want to load a set of default materials and laborTypes from a separate table. It is simple enough if I just wanted to copy data direct from one table to another but in order to populate the existing tables for the new customer, I need to take the seed data (e.g. laborType, laborDescription), add the CompanyID for each row of seed data, then do the insert to the existing table.

What the best method to accomplish this using C# and LINQ with SQL Azure?

An example of a direct insert from user input for LaborTypes is below for contextual reference.

```
using (var context = GetContext(memCustomer))
{
   var u = GetUserByUsername(context, memUser);
   var l = (from lbr in context.LaborTypes
            where lbr.LaborType1.ToLower() == laborType
            && lbr.Company == u.Company
            select lbr).FirstOrDefault();

   if (l == null)
   {
      l = new AccountDB.LaborType();
      l.Company = u.Company;
      l.Description = laborDescription;
      l.LaborType1 = laborType;
      l.FlatRate = flatRate;
      l.HourlyRate = hourlyRate;
      context.LaborTypes.InsertOnSubmit(l);
      context.SubmitChanges();
   }
      result = true;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to :
Create a record in Table A; Those records have seed data stored in Table B and C? Or are you taking in all of these different pieces of information from the user?

Comment: No user input in this part of the so your approach in the first question is correct. I want to create rows in Table A (e.g LaborTypes) using seed data from Table B (e.g. SeedLaborTypes) and adding the CompanyID.

Comment: Did the answer below miss the mark?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is write a query retrieving data from table B and do an Insert Statement on Table A using the result(s).

[This has been covered elsewhere in SO I think, here would be a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080915/insert-select-with-linq-to-sql)

I don't know the syntax for Linq specifically; but by constructing something similar to @Murph 's answer beyond that link, I think this might work.

```
var fromB= from b in TableB
           where ... ;//identify the row/data from table B
// you may need to make fromB populate from the DB here. 
var toInsert = ...; //construct your object with the desired data   
// do other necessary things here        
TableA.InsertAllOnSubmit(toInsert); 
dc.SubmitChanges(); // Submit your changes
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My lack of understanding is what to do for  "//construct your object with the desired data". That is really the core of my question...how do I add a column of data to the query results returned from the seed table. For now I am using datatables but I do hope to find a way to accomplish this in a more efficient manner.